# How to avoid the element slightly fading out when using crossfade transition?

Tags: svelte

When crossfading an image it can be noticed that the element fades out a bit in the middle of the transition. Is there a way to avoid this? Changing the easing doesn't seem to have an effect.

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/33f6e8f2a3864b7b85d59d797f4013b9?version=3.50.1)

**Update** The image might change the position. This might also be solved with toggling classes [like here](https://svelte.dev/repl/0e54e09982a246d99b5b506bac136314?version=3.50.1), but the transition looks different (which maybe might be prevented with different positioning and scaling from the center...), but the unsimplified actual example is a gallery [like this](https://svelte.dev/repl/8a14deb2cf374bc0bcfb96d4d08b4ec5?version=3.50.1) where the element not only scales and moves, but also 'switches' the parent element.

When playing [this video](https://youtu.be/wuFEvYW_phA?t=434) about crossfade at minimum speed, I can't notice any change of the transparency so I wondered if the crossfade function might have changed since. I tried some older compiler versions, but didn't find one without the effect.

Writing a custom transition function is relatively easy, but I couldn't figure out if/how it was possbile to copy and reuse the internal crossfade function with an adjusted opacity setting. Would that be possible somehow?

```
<script>
    import { crossfade } from 'svelte/transition';
    import {quintOut} from 'svelte/easing';

    const [send, receive] = crossfade({
        duration: 3000,
        easing: quintOut
    });

    async function fetchPhoto(noCacheMarker) {
        const response = await fetch(`https://source.unsplash.com/random?${noCacheMarker}`)
        return await response.url
    }

    let smallImg = true
</script>

<button on:click={() => smallImg = !smallImg}>
    toggle
</button>

<div>
    {#await fetchPhoto() then url}
    {#if smallImg}
    <img src="{url}" alt="" id="smallImg"
             out:send="{{key: url}}"
             in:receive="{{key: url}}"
             />
    {:else}
    <img src="{url}" alt="" id="bigImg"
             out:send="{{key: url}}"
             in:receive="{{key: url}}"
             />
    {/if}
    {/await}
</div>

<style>
    img {
        position: absolute;
    }
    #smallImg {
        width: 300px;
        height: 200px;
        object-fit: cover;
        left: 10%;
        bottom: 10%;
    }
    #bigImg {
        width: 600px;
        height: 400px;
        object-fit: cover;
        top: 10%;
        right: 10%;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that two "half transparent" things do not yield one opaque thing but instead something *fairly* opaque. The implementation of the crossfade [is currently faulty in that regard](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/6668).

The only way you do not get some transparency is by always showing the small image and only fading the big one in/out on top.

[REPL example](https://svelte.dev/repl/efe1bac9e8cc4ac493f54280b5930631?version=3.42.0)

If you have to use `crossfade` to also get the correct position transition, you could get [the source from Github](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/blob/master/src/runtime/transition/index.ts) and adjust it. As noted, a proper fix would require that the small image would have to be fully visible during the entire transition but currently the function is symmetrical in that one element fades out, the other fades in.

You can somewhat improve the situation by changing the opacity transition curve, e.g. via exponentiation:

```js
css: (t, u) => `
    opacity: ${t**(1/16) * opacity};
    ...
```

This will result in higher opacity values during the transition, though this approach will never be perfect.

[REPL example](https://svelte.dev/repl/46536dc7c60e435f9d9a43d9a6cab50a?version=3.50.1)

Comment: Thanks H.B., I simplified a bit too much... just added some more info to the question.

Comment: I added a suggestion, though a real solution would require a rewrite of the existing `crossfade`.

Comment: Can't you just do `opacity: ${opacity};`, since both images are the same? If the images are the same, you can just have them both visible all the time I think.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the added example! I was also wondering about the opacity (@Odilf) , why there's even any fading needed when it's the same image. And it does indeed seem to also work when removing the opacity altogether. But looks like the calculation of position and size is not as precise and there's a noticable snap into place at the end of the scaling down. So I can imagine the variant with the small image scaling up and the big fading in/out on top would be better.

Comment: @Odilf: As Corrl noted, if the opacity is not changed you can unfortunately get a noticeable jump from the artifacts generated by the scaling/transform interpolation.

Comment: @Corrl: By the way, the opacity issue has actually been [known for quite a while](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/6668) (just went to check whether it has been reported yet).

Answer (score 1):

It's just that crossfade usually works like this. It also happens in the tutorial, but it's hard to see because of the movement. It is also difficult to explain why this is the case in this answer, but [HTTP 203 have a great episode about this topic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PYSOnC2CrD8).

Probably the best solution is to use CSS transform and transitions. In your example, you just need to add the `transition` property in CSS (you could also use something like `transform: scale(200%)` if you don't want to be messing with DOM layout).

```html
<script>
    import { crossfade } from 'svelte/transition';
    import {quintOut} from 'svelte/easing';

    const [send, receive] = crossfade({
        duration: 3000,
        easing: quintOut
    });

    async function fetchPhoto(noCacheMarker) {
        const response = await fetch(`https://source.unsplash.com/random?${noCacheMarker}`)
        return await response.url
    }

    let smallImg = true
</script>

<button on:click={() => smallImg = !smallImg}>
    toggle
</button>

<div>
    {#await fetchPhoto() then url}
        <img src="{url}" alt="" class={smallImg ? 'small' : 'big'}/>
    {/await}
</div>

<style>
    img {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        transition: all 500ms ease;
    }

    .small {
        width: 300px;
        height: 200px;
        object-fit: cover;
    }

    .big {
        width: 600px;
        height: 400px;
        object-fit: cover;
    }
</style>
```

If you *really* need to use deffered transitions, it might be possible to write your own (since they're customizable) to try fix this problem. But it seems a bad solution and you should probably avoid it.

Comment: Thanks for the link! The example I gave was a bit too simplified, mainly for illustrating the fading... just added some more info.